# Cross-Domain-Iframe in Chrome loading forever without error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, cross-domain

I have this page: http://www.heinzvonheiden.ch/unser-magazin/
The Iframe on the right causes the loading icon to load forever.

I can't figure out why this is happening, i guess its some kind of cross-domain-problem, since on the same page, but with a different domain, its working: http://www.heinzvonheiden.de/unser-magazin/ (But the domain itself isn't written anywhere in the Iframes files)

I also dont get any errors.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that there was a flash inside that iframe, which for some reason didn't prompt the "accept flash on this site".

This caused it, to load forever. On the other domain i already accepted it earlier.